# How to make autocomplete suggestion in javaScript in the right way?

Tags: data-structures, autocomplete

So, i have a big number of different words(7k) from which i could select value. And after typing each word i want to suggest the most suitable words.

Obvious realization from sorting array seems not the best idea, as it should be O(n) time.

For such tasks in smart books people suggest to use Trie data structure, but i release, that in Javascript there is no such build-in structure.

So, what is the right way to autocomplete?

Comment: Sorting 7k strings isn't *that* bad.

Comment: Even if JavaScript has no built-in trie, you could still create one, or find a library for it. If you go for a library, then one that offers an efficient implementation of a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) *might* be the better choice (if you want to search by substrings, not necessarily prefixes). You'll have to benchmark it.